# Check if src image is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if an image url is valid before setting in my img src. At the moment this is what I have:

```
function checkURL(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    
    img.onerror = function () {
        return false;
    }

    img.onload = function () {
        return true;
    }

    img.src = url;
}
```

In both cases is returning **undefined** instead of **true/false**.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uy6kwz9/)

What can I do to solve my issue? I'm using jQuery 3.6.0.

Comment: @jeremy-denis I'm checking the answers in that question to see if they help me but it seems that not, with this code I'm not trying to remove/add some src. I just want to check if the url is valid and return true/false.

Comment: Could you check this example? https://jsfiddle.net/pgecw52q/4/